# Correct treatment for default structs

Tags: c#

I'm currently facing a problem where it would be interesting if there is a better solution.
Assume, I have a struct:

```
public readonly struct PixelSpacing
{
    public static readonly PixelSpacing Empty = new PixelSpacing(0f,0f);

    public readonly float X;
    public readonly float Y;

    public PixelSpacing (float x, float y)
    {
      X = x;
      Y= y;
    }
}
```

How do I discover in a function parameter if it has been a default?

```
public void SetPixelSpacing (PixelSpacing pixelSpacing = default)
```

Of course I could this

```
public void SetPixelSpacing (PixelSpacing pixelSpacing? = default)
{
  PixelSpacing spacing = PixelSpacing.Empty;

  if (pixelSpacing != null)
    spacing = pixelSpacing.Value;

  ...  
}
```

But it seems a bit weird to me to do it like this.
Even though I could use it I need to distinguish between a default constructor and some user created structure, since the default constructor of a struct and the Empty class member are the same, I cannot distinguish where it comes from, so my intention was:

```
public readonly struct PixelSpacing
{
    public static readonly PixelSpacing Empty = new PixelSpacing(0f,0f);
    private readonly bool IsInstance;

    public readonly float X;
    public readonly float Y;

    public PixelSpacing (float x, float y)
    {
      IsInstance = true;
      X = x;
      Y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is PixelSpacing pixelSpacing))
            return false;

        return Equals(pixelSpacing);
    }

    public bool Equals(PixelSpacing other)
    {
        // Check for Empty
        if (!IsInstance && !other.IsInstance)
            return true;

        return
            (Math.Abs(X - other.X) < float.Epsilon) &&
            (Math.Abs(Y - other.Y) < float.Epsilon);
    }             
}
```

so that I can do this:

```
public void SetPixelSpacing (PixelSpacing pixelSpacing = default)
{
  PixelSpacing spacing = PixelSpacing.Empty;

  if (!pixelSpacing.Equals(default)
    spacing = pixelSpacing;

  ...  
}
```

But then I have an extra member only for this tiny little problem.

As this is only an example I need to distinguish in some cases where the behavior of default is different to the behavior of a manually created struct.
This is especially the case where the numbers initialized by the default constructor are different from the numbers of an Empty struct. Especially in the case where there are also string items that needs to be initialized differently in the user created struct than in the default struct.

How would you solve it?

Comment: Your code looks just fine and solves your problem, `Empty` is default struct value in your case, it follows the [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#default-values)

Comment: _the default value of a struct is the value produced by setting all value type fields to their default value_  You can try to declare `Empty` with negative values foe example, to distinguish between `Empty` value and user created struct (if it acceptable for your requirements)

Comment: Why do you even care? Empty and default would carry the same values. If you want to force a non-default parameter, don't make it optional.

Comment: Can you show, using two calls to `SetPixelSpacing`, exactly which two cases you want to differentiate?

Comment: Behind the [door on the right](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ilMjE1Gh3Yg/VpUAmd-6TWI/AAAAAAAAAbg/-FJ08zxN42s/s1600/WFTPM.png).  Use `class` instead of `struct` if this is important.

Comment: @Fildor: In this example you are right, but this is not always the case. For example when it comes to primitive types, like a Physical Number that holds a Physical Value and a Physical Number. Since I cannot hide the default constructor it could happen that a Physical Number is created without any content, and I cannot see this.

Comment: Short of switching to a class, you've already outlined all possible solutions in your question. Pick one. The best way is to ensure the default initialization still yields a meaningful instance, and preferably one that matches what you'd expect for `default` -- you can never prevent a client from explicitly writing `new Struct()` anyway. Where that's not possible, avoid `default` in favor of overloads, or better yet differently-named functions, so the semantics are clear. If you absolutely can't live with default initialization, don't use structs -- it's a feature, not a bug.